# Passing lot of parameters into Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service in ASP.NET a simple one but the web method takes 5 parameters. Is there any other way to pass the parameters? like array or list?. I would like to limit it to 3.

I tried SetMethod(string param) and dint work.

Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you create a Class that has those parameters as it's properties, then you would pass an instance of the class as a parameter to the web method.

Changing something like this..

```
[WebMethod]
public void SomeMethod(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    //some code
}
```

to something like this...

```
[WebMethod]
public void SomeMethod(SomeClass myClass)
{
    //some code
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

and you would use it like so...

```
SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();
myClass.Param1 = "some data";
myClass.Param2 = "more data";
myClass.Param3 = "even more";

// make the webservice call
someObject.SomeMethod(myClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
    [WebMethod]
    public string InsertUserDetails(Student  userInfo)
    { 
        list.Add(userInfo);
        //string Message;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        foreach (Student s in list)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into userdetail(username,password,country,email) values(@UserName,@Password,@Country,@Email)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userInfo.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", userInfo.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", userInfo.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userInfo.Email);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

            //if (result == 1)
            //{
            //    Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";
            //}
            //con.Close();

           // return Message;
        return "done";

    }
```

you can do like this>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: Please provide a little more description about your solution

Comment: I think you are answering some other question. The OP is asking about [tag:web-services] and you are answering about [tag:sql].